# OpenID on PhoneGap Android

Tags: android, cordova, upload, openid, photo

Hello I am developing an app with PhoneGap on Android and am trying to gives users the ability to login to my application and then upload photos and have them saved to their account.  I am planning on using OpenID and have found a few decent resources like http://code.google.com/p/jopenid/ which I am planning on using.

Once I have gotten this working will I have access to the usernames of all users so that I can categorize the photos and their data by that name?  How will I be able to get this information?

Thanks!

Comment: When they log in, you will have access to their username. Then you can insert it into a database.

Comment: How's the progress? I'm doing a similar thing using OpenID to authenticate the user from within a PhoneGap app...I'm a little concerned about how this will work myself, like if I use Google to authenticate, then where will my redirect_to URL be - my phonegap app doesn't necessarily have a URL, does it... :?